# Emacs/Python - function expected an indented block

Tags: python, function, shell, emacs, elpy

I made the switch to Emacs. I am using Elpy within Emacs as an IDE. My setup is side-by-side windows, on the left is a buffer(script) where I write/edit the code which then gets sent to the IPython shell on the right with `Ctrl-Enter`. When I type the function:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd

 data = pd.read_csv('spx_index.csv')

 def convert(x):
     return x.ix[:, 1:].set_index(x.ix[:, 0])
```

into the script (4-space indentation) and press `Ctrl-Enter` twice I get:

```
>>> ...   File "<stdin>", line 2
    return x.ix[:, 1:].set_index(x.ix[:, 0]) 
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

However, when I copy the function and paste it directly into the IPython shell:

```
>>> def convert(x):
    return x.ix[:, 1:].set_index(x.ix[:, 0]) 
... ... 
>>>
```

It works and the function is saved.

Getting the function to run directly from the script to the shell would be ideal. I can't imagine having to copy and paste every function into the shell.

Comment: Does `C-c C-c` work correctly?

Comment: Yes. That works correctly. When I do that the function is saved. That certainly solves my problem. Is there a way to do it line-by-line though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the whole buffer you can press  <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> . You can send the whole region with  <kbd>C-c C-r</kbd>  and you can send the current line that you are by binding the following function. The following function is essentially a copy of `python-shell-send-buffer`

```
(defun python-shell-send-line (&optional send-main msg)
  "Send the entire line to inferior Python process.
When optional argument SEND-MAIN is non-nil, allow execution of
code inside blocks delimited by \"if __name__== \\='__main__\\=':\".
When called interactively SEND-MAIN defaults to nil, unless it's
called with prefix argument.  When optional argument MSG is
non-nil, forces display of a user-friendly message if there's no
process running; defaults to t when called interactively."
  (interactive (list current-prefix-arg t))
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (python-shell-send-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position) send-main msg)))
```

Answer (score 0):

;; this should work, but don't, in your .emacs file:

```
(defun mp-add-python-keys ()
  (interactive)
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-n") 'py-execute-line))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'mp-add-python-keys)
```

Comment: Because you say this does not work, I'm not sure if this is an attempt to answer the question or if it's a new question. If you're asking for help with your own issue, it would be best to post a new question.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.